# Module Problem (about M-injective modules)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, injective-module

Let $U, M$ be $R$-modules. Show that the following assertions are
equivalent:

(a) $U$ is $M$-injective;

(b) every morphism $f : I → U$, $I$ a left ideal in $R$, with $R/ \ker f ∈ σ[M]$,
can be extended to $R$.

Comment: What have you tried? What is this notation $\sigma [M]$? And what is the definition of $M$-injective?

Comment: U is called M-injective  if  the map
Hom(f, U) : Hom(M, U) → Hom(K, U)
is surjective for every monomorphism f : K → M.

Comment: We say that an R-module N is subgenerated by M, or that M is a subgenerator for N, if N is isomorphic to a submodule of an M-generated module. A subcategory C of R-MOD is subgenerated by M, or M is a subgenerator for C, if every object in C is subgenerated by M.
We denote by σ[M] the full subcategory of R-MOD whose objects are
all R-modules subgenerated by M.